# How may I retrieve the current date output from TimeSliderChoropleth (the one displayed in the slider)?

Tags: python, time, folium, timeslider

How may I retrieve the current date output from [TimeSliderChoropleth](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/folium/plugins/time_slider_choropleth.py)?

[image showing current date displayed in the timeslider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpLnx.png)

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import TimeSliderChoropleth  
  
base_map = folium.Map(location=[33,22])
    
time_slider = TimeSliderChoropleth(
        data=data,
        styledict=style_dict
        )   
time_slider.add_to(base_map)
```

I understand that [these tests](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/tests/plugins/test_time_slider_choropleth.py) may provide hints on how I might retrieve that info, but I am not currently proficient enough in JS or python to figure out how.

I am looking to get the same type of functionality that can be achieved using plotly ([map at the bottom of this webpage](https://amaral.northwestern.edu/blog/step-step-how-plot-map-slider-represent-time-evolu)).

Answer (score 0):

As seen in this small snippet from the plugin definition, the Folium python TimeSliderChloropleth plugin adds html DOM objects as children to the "base" html DOM object.

[image]

So anytime (*after* the Chloropleth has been created) if you want the value as a javascript variable, you can either

1. access the text value directly from the DOM as:

   document.getElementById("slider-value")[0].innerHTML

or

2. manage your own javascript variable and listener to keep that variable constantly updated: *(note, surround all of this by script and end-script tags...they cannot be typed into SE editor for safety)*

   //First you need a js variable to place the timecode into

   var timecode_formatted = '';

   //Next you need a js function as a listener to the time_slider object change event

   document.getElementById("slider-value").onchange =
   function(){
   timecode_formatted =
   document.getElementById("slider-value")[0].innerHTML;

   //At this point the "timecode_formatted" javascript variable should be populated with the text that is shown in the time slider

Comment: Hi @jasoninvegas. Thank you for your reply.   

time_slider is a python variable, so `time_slider.onchange` leads to a python attribute error because that's JS object manipulation.   

How can I manipulate the JS from `_template.module.script` that is being used in the folium python package ("under the hood") so that I may retrieve the current slider timecode in python?

Comment: Ok, my bad. I am adjusting my answer based on the interplay between Folium (python) and Leaflet (javascript)

Comment: Thank you again @jasoninvegas. Do you know how might I access the JS-generated values directly from folium using python packages? I am using Streamlit to display the folium map and need to access these variables directly from the python code. I've tried using BeautifulSoup and base_map.get_root().html ( or .render() ) but didn't manage to find a way to use document.getElementById("slider-value")[0].innerHTML as you sugest.

Comment: Unfortunately that's too niche for even me! I suggest posting in the Python SE channels with Streamlit and JavaScript tags.